# Metascraper Consolidated Data

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors, web-crawler

I'm using metascraper in a project I'm working on. I'm passing in custom rules into the contructor. It's actually scraping actual content from the page its scraping. The problem is, is that it appears to be finding every tag that matches the CSS selector, and combining all of the text() content from every tag on the page. I checked metascraper website and github and couldn't find any information about an option that changes this kind of mode/behavior. I made sure that each scrape request creates a new instance of metascraper in case it was just using the same member variables across multiple uses of the object, but that didn't seem to do anything. Any thoughts?

Edit: Also, ideally, metascraper would return an array of arrays of sets of selectors it finds. I have 4 selectors in a group that appear in groups throughout a page. I need it to iterate over the selectors in order, until it cannot find any more instances of the 1st selector (aka the groups have stopped appearing on the page).

```
type4: async (page: Page): Promise<Extract[]> => {

  const html     = await page.content()
  const url      = await page.url()

  const type4MetascraperInstance = createType4MetaScraperInstance()
  const metadata = await type4MetascraperInstance({ html: html, url: url })

  console.log('metadata: ', metadata)

  const extract: Extract[] = [{
    fingerprint: 'type4',
    author:       metadata.author,
    body:         metadata.description,
    images:       null,
    logo:         null,
    product:      null,
    rating:       null,
    title:        metadata.title,
    videos:       null
  }]

  return extract
}
```

The function for creating the Type4 metascraper instance is:

```
function createType4MetaScraperInstance() {

  const toDescription = toRule(description)
  const toAuthor = toRule(author)
  const toTitle  = toRule(title, { removeSeparator: false })

  const type4MetaScraperInstance = metaScraper([ {
      author: [
        toAuthor($ => $('.a-profile-name').text()),
      ],
      title: [
        toTitle($ => $('a[data-hook="review-title"] > span').text()),
      ],
      description: [
        toDescription($ => $('.review-text-content').text()),
      ]
  } ])

  return type4MetaScraperInstance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to architect a different solution here that uses a python script to properly parse reviews, and it will need to read/write to google cloud datastore. Some suggestions people provided were to write my own calls to cheeriojs (https://cheerio.js.org/), instead of using metascraper at all.